# uploading videos in Djnago rest framework

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework, django-celery, django-signals

I have created an post api which will upload images and videos for blogs. I can handle multiple images, not a problem there. But I have to send a video as well from the frontend. I have used Filefield for video. I am no expert in apis but what I think is, since the code I have written is synchronous, everything that I have written will be be done at the same time. Now the issue is, if a user wants to upload a very large video for eg 200-500 mb then, the post api call response will be very long. Is there a way I can save the blog post first, return the response and then start uploading the video in the database of live server.

My models:

```
class Blogposts(models.Model):  
        
    blog_title = models.CharField(max_length=100blank=True)   

    video  = models.FileField(upload_to="media",                             
                                     null= True)
```

I tried to use django signals, but then again django signals are also synchronous.Everything I stated above might be wrong as well, I am not sure. But how to approach this?? Or should I use django celery??

Comment: Do a separate request for the video?

Comment: I dont know what is the best approach...my thinking is created a blog post first without the video and later start uploading the video asychronously.

Comment: Yes. Just create two separate requests. Create the post, get its id back. Then upload the video, using the id to attach it to the correct post.

Comment: hmn,...what about the time taken to upload the video on the form of the frontend itself??

Comment: Well ideally you would not use a plain form but some kind of JS to perform a [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) in the background.

Comment: sorry i am new to this...but does that mean, it will first take time to upload in the frontend form and then after uploading, it again takes time to upload it to db at the prod server??? after post api call.

Comment: You normally do not store files in a database server to begin with. The exact details of how you deal with files depends on your overall deployment. That's something you have to design. There is more to a fully working website than the application tier :)

Answer (score 2):

DRF already have partial updates. Use that. Meaning, you make a post request for only the non file fields. Make the video field blank true null true.

Once its done successfully, you get back the id of your post in response. Then make a patch request to upload the file.

Your javascript algo can look roughly like this

```
const handleFormSubmit => (data) {
  file = data.video_file;
  delete data.video_file;
  axios.post('/blogs/', data).then(response => {
    updateUiShowCreatedBlogWithVideoUploading();

    id = response.id;
    fileUploadRequestData = {
      file: file
    }
    axios.patch('/blogs/${id}/', file).then(response => {
      updateUiShowCreatedBlogWithVideoUploaded();
    });
  });
}
```

But in general, for large files I would directly upload it to an object store (like S3) from the browser and not bother django process. Once it's done, attache the object like in the patch. In this case your model will just a URL field and not FileField.

If that's too much, at-least use django-storages and let the library handle uploading to S3 from your backend.

Comment: s3 is used if we used aws as a server for backend? what if we use digital ocean or something like that @Amrit??

Comment: Any object store is fine. DigitalOcean Spaces have the same API as S3. But I haven't tried the browser to storage with Spaces. Plus videos are a bit too complex in general and better to deal with it separately. Uploading is just one part. then transcoding and serving. If you serve it directly from your VM, you will soon hit your transfer limits.

Comment: So as you said "DRF already have partial updates. Use that. Meaning, you make a post request for only the non file fields. Make the video field blank true null true.

Once its done successfully, you get back the id of your post in response. Then make a patch request to upload the file." by doing this, will it solve problems like you said in serving etc?? also do i make a put request or patch??

Comment: Not at all. It just solves your async problem - makes the user not wait for all 200MB upload to finish. For the rest it depends on your requirements actually. If you are the only one uploading videos - don't worry much and FileField is just fine with `django-storages` setup (DO Spaces with CDN enabled solves the serving problem). And you are responsible for making bandwidth / user device friendly videos locally. Otherwise checkout https://aws.amazon.com/elastictranscoder/ . I made something many years ago as well https://transcode.io/ but never managed to sell it :p

Comment: @Reactoo I see you haven’t marked this as answer yet. Let me know if you have any more queries :)